# Invisible HTML form

Tags: html, css, authentication, joomla

I have a weird problem here. On one of my websites running Joomla! is the login form - http://bohemia-kichijoji.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login . What I have noticed, the login form is invisible in Firefox (tested on 4.0.)m but visible on other browsers. I have tried almost everything - went through CSS, HTML, run validation - nothing helped. Could you please tell me the reason, why this happens?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's getting pushed outside the page, try this:

```
fieldset {
    clear:left;
}
```

OR

```
table.contentpane {
    float:none; /* or remove the float:left; */
}
```

There didn't seem to be any reason to float the table, so personally I'd use option 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have a floating problem. The Element before your fieldset element which is table is floated left. you have not cleared you floats. There are many ways around this. You could use the overflow property on the form element or you could clear the float on the filedset element itself as follows.

```
fieldset {clear: left;}
```

Or do like this

```
form {overflow: auto;}
```

This will cause the fieldset element to appear in Firefox 4.0 and Firefox 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It is because of using  which is causing it to not display in Firefox.

You'll need to remove the fieldset for Firefox and see it it works..